# Why is cursor fetch always returning top row when there are multiple rows?

Tags: c, oracle

I am trying to get unique file names stored in a table which has the oldest modified date stored.

```
 EXEC SQL AT  DECLARE CtrlIndexTLOGNames_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT cDataSrcFileName
    FROM SC_CTRL_XMLBUFFER
    GROUP BY cDataSrcFileName
    ORDER BY MAX(modifieddatetime) asc;

EXEC SQL FETCH CtrlIndexTLOGNames_cursor INTO :s_cDataSrcFileName;
```

Pro*C Code:

```
BOOLEAN CXYZ::GetSCCtrlTLOGFileName()
{
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;

        char cDataSrcFileName[SZ_FILENAME+30];
        char cSetSortorder[5];
        char s_cAtTable[80];

    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    BOOLEAN bOpenFail=false;
    BOOLEAN bRet=false;

    //char  s_append[500];
    sqlca.sqlcode = null;

    // Always start with a clean error structure
    ClearLastError();

    // Make sure that we close the cursor if it is opened
    CloseCursor();

    ClearLastError();

    // Make sure it is OK to proceed
    if (m_bDBConn)
    {
        // Next check to see that DB is available
        memset(s_cAtTable, 0, sizeof(s_cAtTable));
        if (m_pSup->DBActive(m_lDBType))
            m_pSup->DBAtString(m_lDBType, s_cAtTable, sizeof(s_cAtTable));
        else
            m_lDBType=DAI_PRIMARY;

        // Here we access the appropriate table
        if (m_lDBType == DAI_PRIMARY)
        {
            // Get the row count from the table

             EXEC SQL DECLARE CtrlIndexTLOGNames_cursor CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT cDataSrcFileName
                FROM SC_CTRL_XMLBUFFER
                GROUP BY cDataSrcFileName
                ORDER BY MAX(modifieddatetime) asc;

            // Check to see if the cursor declare succeeded
            if (sqlca.sqlcode == 0)
            {
                EXEC SQL OPEN CtrlIndexTLOGNames_cursor;
                m_lCursorCode=SCCURCTRLXMLBUFFER;
                m_bCursorOpen=true;
                bRet = true;
            }
            else
                bOpenFail=true;
        }
        else
        {
            EXEC SQL AT :s_cAtTable DECLARE CtrlIndexTLOGNames_cursor_B CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT cDataSrcFileName
                FROM SC_CTRL_XMLBUFFER
                GROUP BY cDataSrcFileName
                ORDER BY MAX(modifieddatetime) asc;

                // Check to see if the cursor declare succeeded
            if (sqlca.sqlcode == 0)
            {
                EXEC SQL OPEN CtrlIndexTLOGNames_cursor_B;
                m_lCursorCode=SCCURCTRLXMLBUFFER_B;
                m_bCursorOpen=true;
                bRet = true;
            }
            else
                bOpenFail=true;
        }

        // Check to make sure the open succeeded
        if(!bOpenFail)
        {
            if (sqlca.sqlcode == 0)
                bRet=true;
            else
            {
                // Report the failure information
                sprintf(m_cLastError, (char *)"RTPSC  CtrlIndexTLOGNames CURSOR open failed[%d]:", sqlca.sqlcode);

                // Here we append the RDBMS string
                strncat(m_cLastError, sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc, sizeof(m_cLastError)-(strlen(m_cLastError)+2));

                // Here we set the appropriate control information
                m_lLastError = sqlca.sqlcode;
                m_bDBConn=false;
                m_pSup->Show(VBL_MINIMAL,m_cLastError);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Report the failure information
            sprintf(m_cLastError, (char *)"RTP5003E:CtrlIndexTLOGNames CURSOR declaration failed[%d]:", sqlca.sqlcode);

            // Here we append the RDBMS string
            strncat(m_cLastError, sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc, sizeof(m_cLastError)-(strlen(m_cLastError)+2));

            // Here we set the appropriate control information
            m_lLastError = sqlca.sqlcode;
            m_bDBConn=false;
            m_pSup->Show(VBL_MINIMAL,m_cLastError);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(m_cLastError, (char *)"RTP9101E:Transaction class was not properly initialized.");
        m_lLastError=EFAULT;
    }

    // Close out an ERROR'd cursor
    if (!bRet) CloseCursor();

    // Return the results of this action
    return(bRet);
}


BOOLEAN CZYZ::GetSCCtrlNextTLOGFileName( char *&pFileName)
{
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION; 

        char s_cDataSrcFileName[SZ_FILENAME+35];
        char s_cAtTable[80];

    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    BOOLEAN bRet=false;
    long lDataSize;

    // Clear out the last error before diving in to the process
    ClearLastError();

    // Make sure that the caller's storage starts out clean
    pFileName=(char *)null;

    // Next make sure we have access to the database
    if (m_bDBConn && (m_lCursorCode == SCCURCTRLXMLBUFFER || m_lCursorCode == SCCURCTRLXMLBUFFER_B))
    {
        // Next check to see that DB is available
        memset(s_cAtTable, 0, sizeof(s_cAtTable));
        if (m_pSup->DBActive(m_lDBType))
            m_pSup->DBAtString(m_lDBType, s_cAtTable, sizeof(s_cAtTable));
        else
            m_lDBType=DAI_PRIMARY;

        if (m_lCursorCode == SCCURCTRLXMLBUFFER)
        {
            //printf("Inside m_lCursorCode == SCCURCTRLXMLBUFFER condition\n");
            // Pull the information back from the database
            EXEC SQL FETCH CtrlIndexTLOGNames_cursor INTO :s_cDataSrcFileName;
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("Inside m_lCursorCode == SCCURCTRLXMLBUFFER_B condition\n");
            // Pull the information back from the database
            EXEC SQL FETCH CtrlIndexTLOGNames_cursor_B INTO :s_cDataSrcFileName;
        }
        // Check to see if the cursor declare succeeded
        if (sqlca.sqlcode == 0)
        {
            lDataSize=strlen((char *)s_cDataSrcFileName)+2L;
            // Here we allocate the storage as needed
                if ((pFileName=new char[lDataSize]) != (char *)null)
                {
                    // Here we move the data into this storage
                    memset(pFileName, 0, lDataSize);
                    strncpy(pFileName, s_cDataSrcFileName, lDataSize-1L);
                    bRet=true;
                    CleanWhiteSpace(pFileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Here we mark this failure for the caller
                    sprintf(m_cLastError, (char *)"RTP1000E:Memory Allocation Failed requesting %lu bytes (rc=%ld).", lDataSize, errno);
                    m_lLastError=ENOMEM;
                    bRet=false;
                }
        }
        else if (sqlca.sqlcode != DBERR_NOTFOUND && sqlca.sqlcode != DBERR_NODATAFOUND)
        {
            // Report the failure information
            sprintf(m_cLastError, (char *)"RTP8323E:GLOAD CtrlIndexTLOGNames CURSOR fetch failed[%d]:", sqlca.sqlcode);

            // Here we append the RDBMS string
            strncat(m_cLastError, sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc, sizeof(m_cLastError)-(strlen(m_cLastError)+2));

            // Here we set the appropriate control information
            m_lLastError = sqlca.sqlcode;
            m_bDBConn=false;
            m_pSup->Show(VBL_MINIMAL,m_cLastError);
            bRet=false;
        }
        if (!bRet)
        {
            // Here is the cursor close
            CloseCursor();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(m_cLastError, (char *)"RTP9101E:RTPSC class was not properly initialized.");
        m_lLastError=EFAULT;
    }

    // Here we return the results of this action
    return(bRet);   
}
```

When I run this query, i get multiple rows with unique filenames. But when I use the function in my C code using while loop, this always returns top row and not other filenames.

Can you please let me what is wrong with this?

In C Module I call the Pro*C functions

```
// Get list of file names
    if(!CXYZ.GetSCCtrlTLOGFileName())
    {
      printf("\n\nERROR creating cursor in SC_CTRL_XMLBUFFER Database Class: 
      \n%s\n\n", cErrorMsg);
      return iRet=EIO;
    }

    while (CXYZ.GetSCCtrlNextTLOGFileName(pFile))
    {
     printf("UpdateWorkFlowListFromDB pFile - %s\n",pFile);
     .
     .
     .
    }
```

Also,

Is there a limit to number of open cursors?

from my environment:

```
               select name,value from v$parameter where name like '%cursor%';

               cursor_space_for_time    FALSE
               session_cached_cursors   50
               cursor_sharing   EXACT
               open_cursors 1000
               cursor_bind_capture_destination  memory+disk

              select count(*) from V$OPEN_CURSOR;

             1430
```

Could this be the reason for the issue?

Comment: You fetch only one time I think. Should it not be fetching in a loop until a fetch returns empty for cursor ?

Comment: I have the oracle based query in my Pro*C code and have the loop that you are mentioning about (While loop that i have given above), in the C/C++ module.

Comment: @UmeshNarayananSrinivasan - you need to show a more complete view of your code. It kind of sounds like you are doing both the declare and fetch inside the loop; are both `EXEC` calls inside the function you are calling in the loop?

Comment: No, I have two functions in Pro*C.
GetSCCtrlTLOGFileName() has the Declare and the Select statement. I also open the cursor here.
GetSCCtrlNextTLOGFileName() is the function where i do the fetch of the column.
Then I call these functions in my C module and have the GetSCCtrlNextTLOGFileName() in while loop which i have shown in my first comment. Hope this explains you how i have implemented my logic.

Comment: I am allowed few characters to print here in StackOverflow, so I am not able to show my two functions from Pro*C.

Comment: @UmeshNarayananSrinivasan - please **edit your question** (there's an `edit` button just beneath the question tags, above) and add the additional code. Do not put code, data, or further explanations into a comment as it will very likely be overlooked. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the Question. Added the Pro*C functions as asked.